# Print object pointer address passed by reference

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", str);
[self doSomthingWithString:&str];

- (void)doSomthingWithString:(NSString **)str {
    *str = @"world";
    NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", *str);
}
```

Maybe it's kind of obvious question, but I expect to have **same** address printed out:

```
Pointer = 0x104ce9f40
Pointer = 0x104ce9fa0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not see the same address printed, because `doSomthingWithString` assigns a new object to `str` from the caller. It does *not* modify `NSString` in place.

The `NSString` with the content `"Hello"` that was referenced by `str` is no longer referenced after the assignment `*str = @"world"`, hence the different printout.

Perhaps a better illustration would be with a separate string for `"world"`, like this:

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", str);        // Prints @"hello"'s address ad
[self doSomthingWithString:&str];

- (void)doSomthingWithString:(NSString **)str {
    NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", *str);   // Prints @"hello"'s address again
    NSString *other = @"world";
    NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", *other); // Prints @"world"'s address
    *str = other;
    NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", *str);   // Prints @"world"'s address again
}
```

Comment: so it doesn't change the value at existing address but rather create new value and assign new address (with actully same value) and my original string address also changes?

Comment: @Injectios Yes, if you add another `NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", str)` after returning from `doSomthingWithString` you would see the address of `@"world"` string object.

Comment: yes, sure your updated answer makes me ashamed, ofc by assigning = @"world" its a new pointer, new memory

Comment: @Injectios Note that the behavior would be different with `NSMutableString` passed in the regular way (i.e. without the second asterisk) if you replaced the content with some other value. `NSString`, however, is immutable: once the content is in, it's in for good.